# Floating label, How to get a result in .ts?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a simple question but I can't resolve it. I have a floating label in my .html like this:

```
<ion-list>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label floating >Username</ion-label>
                    <ion-input type="text" ></ion-input>

                </ion-item>

                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
                    <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

How can I get username and password in my .ts file?
Thanks in advance!

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ngModel` like you can see [in Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)

```
<ion-list>
   <ion-item>
     <ion-label floating >Username</ion-label>
     <ion-input [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" type="text" ></ion-input>
   </ion-item>

   <ion-item>
     <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
     <ion-input [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" type="password"></ion-input>
   </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

And in your .ts code:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage {

  private username: string;
  private password: string;

  constructor() { 

  }
}
```

So in the code you can use the `username` and `password` properties to access the values the user entered in the view. Please take a look at [Angular 2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) to learn more about this and some other topics related to forms.

---

**EDIT**

Since `Ionic 2-beta.11` uses the new Angular Forms, you would need to check a few additional things to make it work:

First, please check the *dependencies* in you `package.json` file, to be sure you have something like this:

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
"ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.11",
"ionic-native": "1.3.10",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"zone.js": "0.6.12"
```

It may be slightly different, but the important thing is that the angular stuff uses the `2.0.0-rc.4` version, and also that the `"@angular/forms": "0.2.0",` dependency is included.

Then, in your `app.ts` file you have to import

```
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';
```

And in your `ionicBootstrap` call those methods to disable the deprecated forms, and enable the new forms module instead

```
ionicBootstrap(YourAppName, 
  [
    disableDeprecatedForms(),  // disable deprecated forms
    provideForms()             // enable new forms module
  ], {});
```

And then, in the page where you have the form, just import things related to forms from `@angular/forms`. Please check that you don't import things related to forms from other any module (like `@angular/core`).

```
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: Thanks for reply me! but when I add:

[(ngModel)]="username" name="username"

I have this error: browser_adapter.js:84 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in build/pages/home/home.html:32:31
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No value accessor for ''
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: No value accessor for ''
    at new BaseException (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:2323:23)
    at _throwError (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:4868:11)
    at Object.setUpControl (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:4843:9)
......

You know why?

Comment: Yeah... which version of Ionic2 are you using? You can run `ionic info` to know it btw

Comment: Yes, beta 11, I show you:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.37
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
OS:
Node Version: v4.4.5

Comment: Thanks you!! :) 
In this link this issue is resolved because my problem was to upgrade to beta 1. If someone needs...